# Function C+Dx closest f(x) = sin2x on the interval from −π to π by least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation, least-squares

I am a little bit confused over the second part of the following problem:

21. What is the closest function acos x +bsinx to the function f(x) = sin2x on the interval from −π to π? What is the closest straight line c+dx? (from Linear Algebra and Its Applications by Gilbert Strang p.210)

What I thought:

Given the function g(x) = C+Dx = $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & x \\
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
C \\
D
\end{array} \right)
$ I can solve the equation g(x)=f(x) $\Longleftrightarrow$ $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & x \\
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
C \\
D
\end{array} \right)
$ = $\sin(2x)$ by least squares:
$$Ax=b$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow  A^TA \hat x = A^Tb$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
x
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & x \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat C \\
\hat D
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
x
\end{array}
\right) \sin(2x)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
(1,1) & (1,x) \\
(x,1) & (x,x)
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat C \\
\hat D
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
(1,\sin(2x) \\
(x, \sin(2x)
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1 \cdot 1)dx & \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1 \cdot x)dx \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x \cdot 1)dx & \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x \cdot x)dx
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat C \\
\hat D
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1 \cdot \sin(2x))dx \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x \cdot \sin(2x))dx
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2\pi & 0 \\
0 & \frac{2\pi^3}{3}
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat C \\
\hat D
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
-\pi
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\hat C \\
\hat D
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
\frac{-3}{2\pi^2}
\end{array}
\right).$$

Hence: $g(x) = \frac{-3}{2\pi^2}x$. However the solution states that $\hat C,\hat D = 0$ so $g(x)=0+0x$. If I look at the function in geogebra, $\hat C,\hat D=0$ is worse than $\hat C=0$, $\hat D=\frac{-3}{2\pi^2}$ but there seem to be even (slighly) better lines. There must be some error in my calculations but I cannot find it. Could somebody help me at this problem?

Comment: I've got the same result as you did by minimizing $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(C+Dx-\sin2x)^2dx$$with respect to $C$ and $D$

Comment: Okay thank you for the verification, it could also be due to rounding error (if I try e. g. D=-0.2 I get a slighly smaller error) and maybe the solution is just wrong